# How to login with local project after installing ssl certification on operating system

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

it's a bit complicate to explain what i've got here.

here, I hava a groupware to manage(maintain as well). a week ago, my customer got installed ssl certification on their server. after that, some problems were submit to me which are usual. To take a look and fix the things i got to run the project at my local pc via eclipse. everything was good till I try to log - in which means I got log-in page with no problems. once i tried to log in i meet page of "connection dinied" and url change from `http://localhost:8888/gw/test/login.do` to `https://localhost:444/gw/test/login.do`

my local project face every each server of operation system such as messenger, erp, groupware database server etc but not websever. web is local that is the reason at the first time, i couldn't think it's not a sslproblem.

I have an openssl cert my own, i wrote infomation of this in server.xml
like below

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
          maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
          keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\key_kohi.jks"
          keystorePass="123456" sslEnabledProtocol="TLS" 
          />
```

Comment: <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
              maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
              keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\key_kohi.jks"
              keystorePass="123456" sslEnabledProtocol="TLS" 
              />

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).